# parse json results using NSJSONSerialization

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am trying to parse this json:

```
{
    "myData": [
        {
            "date": "2013-07-29",
            "preferredMeetingLocation": "home",
            "isbn": null,
            "category": "Clothing",
            "price": "5",
            "title": "clothingstuff",
            "description": "Desc"
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-07-29",
            "preferredMeetingLocation": "home2",
            "isbn": null,
            "category": "Clothing",
            "price": "2",
            "title": "other",
            "description": "Desc2"
        }
    ]
}
```

So far I have:

```
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    NSDictionary *results = [json objectForKey:@"myData"];
for (NSDictionary *item in results) {
    NSLog(@"results::%@", [results objectForKey:@"title"]);
}
```

but I get `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8877e40'`

The main goal is to be able to parse the data received and then display each set of info in a cell.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're doing precisely what the message says you're doing:  Trying to perform "objectForKey" on an NSArray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
 NSLog(@"results::%@", [results objectForKey:@"title"]);
 //                        ^---- Wrong variable used here!
```

should be

```
 NSLog(@"results::%@", [item objectForKey:@"title"]);
```

Comment: ah shoot thanks, also if I want to get the count for how much items came back, in this case 2, how do I get that? I think its something like `[[results allKeys] count];` but that crashes as well

Comment: @BluGeni: Note that `results` should be an *array*: `NSArray *results = ...` as @rmaddy correctly said in his answer. And then `[results count]` should work.

Answer (score 1):

`results` should be an array. And you are logging the wrong object.

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSArray *results = [json objectForKey:@"myData"];
for (NSDictionary *item in results) {
    NSLog(@"title::%@", [item objectForKey:@"title"]);
}
```